# File History not working Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, raid, ntfs, file-management, history

I have file history turned on yet no data is saved.
When I turn FH off and then on I get an error message: "File History has found files that are encrypted with Encrypting File System, on a network location, or on a drive that doesn't use the the NTFS file system. These files won't be backed up."
When I turn on file history I get the message that File History is saving copies of my files but nothing is written to the backup disk.
I have tried backing up to my C drive but that doesn't work either.
I have a Dell Studio XPS 435t / 9000 running Intel Rapid Share Raid 1 with four 1tb drives as C and D. I update from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 8 and then Windows 8.1.
I have a WD external 2TB drive with 1.3 GB free. (I have a system image of both my drives.)
I have searched for EFS files or directories but none exist. None of the drives are a network location. Everything is NTFS. All the security permissions are correct (as far as I can tell.)
When I press Run Now the date saved is not updated.
I cannot find anyone with this problem.
Help!
Regards,
Chris

Answer (score -1):

It could be the Windows Search is turned off in services.msc.  run/services.msc/windows search.  I had the same problem and that cured it by turning on the Windows serarch service.